# Posting Model with image in .Net 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

I am using .Net 5 for building a Web API, I have a model that contains an image and I want to POST the model with the image to save the image into the file system and take the image path into the database.

Let's say we have our model:

```
    public partial class Document
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string imageUrl { get; set; }   
    }
```

I tried:

```
    [Route("api/Images")]
    public class ImageController : Controller
    {

        [HttpPost("upload")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file)
        {
            try
            {
                var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/images", file.FileName);
                var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
                file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                return Ok(new { length = file.Length, name = file.FileName });
            }
            catch
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }

    }
```

I still need to pass my model with the image file.

Comment: Did you [read the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads)?

Comment: yes, i checked 
the form contains only file, not more model props

Comment: Binary data in html can only be sent to ways 1) Convert to base 64 string 2) Add to message as a Mime attachment.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To upload the image file into database via Asp.net core API, first, we should use `IFormFile` to send the image file from the client to the API action method. Then, save the `IFormFile` into the file system and take the image path into the database.

You could refer the following sample, in this sample, I use a View model to let user enter values and upload image.

In Web API, using the following model:

```
//the view model, used to transfer the user entered value and the image file.
public class FileViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IFormFile File { get; set; } 
}
```

API Upload action method:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("upload")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadImageProfile([FromForm] FileViewModel fileviewmodel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/images", fileviewmodel.File.FileName);
            var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
            await fileviewmodel.File.CopyToAsync(stream);
            //create a Document instance, and insert value into database.

            return Ok(new { length = fileviewmodel.File.Length, name = fileviewmodel.File.FileName });
        }
        catch
        {
            return BadRequest();
        } 
        return Ok("");
    }
    return Ok("Invalid");
}
```

Then, in the MVC view page, use the JQuery Ajax to upload the form data and preview the image.

```
@model WebApplication6.Models.FileViewModel

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form id="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-action="FileUpload">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <dl>
                    <dt>
                        <label asp-for="File"></label>
                    </dt>
                    <dd>
                        <input asp-for="File" type="file">
                    </dd>
                </dl>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group"> 
                <input type="button" id="btnsubmit" value="Ajax Create" class="btn btn-primary"  />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts{ 
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#btnsubmit").click(function () {
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('name', $("#Name").val())
            fd.append('file', $('#File')[0].files[0]);

            $.ajax({
                url: "/api/todo/upload",
                data: fd,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                method: "post",
                headers: {
                    RequestVerificationToken:
                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
                },
                success: function (response) { 
                  
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

The result like this:

[image]

More detail information about uploading files, see: [Upload files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0).